# 3.3 Keymap for 2.79

Tags: rendering, shortcut, customization, keymap

I have been doing some retro looking renders in 2.79 as of late, but I am unfamiliar with its Keymap and switching between 3.3 and 2.79 breaks my workflow quite a bit. Is there any way to quickly update 2.79's keymap?

Comment: Highly unlikely I would imagine. If you could say and post an image of what sort of "retro looking renders" you want I'm sure someone will be able to suggest how you can create them in blender 3.3.

Comment: I will do so! Thank you for the suggestion. I will keep this question unanswered in the event that someone solves the initial issue.